# Syntax to query accounts in hierarchy between top and a specific child

Tags: soql

I need to query all of the accounts between a specific child account and the ultimate parent account at the top of the hierarchy and am uncertain what syntax to use for the query. The number of children in between the two accounts can vary between none and up to 5 or 6 levels. I will have both the "ultimate account" number available to me and the child account number available to me.

What I've written so far, looks like this:

```
[SELECT ID, Name, Parent, Account_Parent__C FROM Account WHERE (Account_Parent__c =: Var1
  OR Parent.ID =: Var1 AND ID !=: Var1) <-- last condition excludes ultimate parent 
  AND (Id !=: Var2 OR ParentId !=: Var2) <-- excludes nth child ];
```

I don't know for certain how to state in the query that `var2` is the Id of the `nth child` of the ultimate parent. `Account_Parent__c` or Var 1 is the Id of the ultimate parent. Var2 is the Id of the nth child account. Does anyone see a more specific method to assure I get the correct accounts?

Unfortunately, I don't have sufficient test data available to me to reliably test this in our sandbox, so wanted to ask for suggestions before I invested time and energy trying to create data to confirm that it works.

Comment: Why do you specifically need via query ? We can use maps and trace back all accounts from ultimate parent ?

Comment: Where I have hierarchically related objects I'll often have a custom field that holds a lookup to the ultimate parent record. This can make finding all the descendants easy in SOQL. Otherwise relationship queries should get you to 5 levels deep.

Comment: You won't be able to retrieve the specific results in a single query. You will have to use Maps, to get results.

Comment: @DanielBallinger. `Account_Parent__c` is essentially a look-up to the ultimate parent that's listed on each account of this RecordType. I'm trying to get the names of the Accounts in between to quickly generate a select option list for a mobile app.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava. Any time you're doing a getAccount from a custom controller, you're running a query. I have the child account with the lookup to the ultimate as the start point. Regardless of what I do, I will need to run a query to get the ultimate account and it's children to create the maps you speak of. Why not have SOQL give me the direct path if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @DanielBallinger mentioned in the comments, I have seen `Ultimate_Parent__c` formulas work quite successfully to simplify these problems. They go something along the lines of:

```
IF(ParentId = null, Id,
    IF(Parent.ParentId = null, ParentId,
    IF(Parent.Parent.ParentId = null, Parent.ParentId,
    etc
)))
```

If you want to understand hierarchy depth, you could use a slightly modified version of the above:

```
IF(ParentId = null, 1,
    IF(Parent.ParentId = null, 2,
    IF(Parent.Parent.ParentId = null, 3,
    etc
)))
```

Performing queries with the above data should be much easier. For example, if you have an `Account` and want to find all records between a specific child and the ultimate parent, you would do:

```
SELECT Id FROM Account
WHERE HierarchyDepth__c > 1
AND HierarchyDepth__c < :contextAccount.HierarchyDepth__c
AND UltimateParent__c = :contextAccount.UltimateParent__c
```

Comment: `Account_Parent__c` is indeed a look-up to the ultimate parent. This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Would I need to create a class for HierarchyDepth or is this something you're doing with a custom object and or field perhaps using CASE?? That part is unclear to me in terms of implementing it in a query.

Comment: I think formula is fine. I'm not sure it can be done with a `CASE` statement.

Comment: @crmprogdev I'm not sure if I need to add more detail. I would love to be more helpful but I don't know how.

Comment: What you've provided was great Adrian. I'm confident you know how things can change with the wind direction in this business. Not surprisingly, requirements changed today. It was a nice exercise and I learned something from it. LOL! Thanks for everything. I liked your solution and have been swamped all day.

Comment: Haha. It's called "job security"